# App on vercel fails to connect with AWS RDS

Tags: next.js, amazon-rds, prisma, vercel, prisma2

I am facing trouble when my app written using NextJS with PrismaIO as database ORM deployed to Vercel tries to connect with MYSQL database which is hosted on AWS RDS fails due to time out. It shows below error after a while:

```
502: BAD_GATEWAY
Code: NO_RESPONSE_FROM_FUNCTION
ID: bom1::zrmv2-1609789429213-86b5142a230c
```

I have added my app hosted at Vercel's IP address whitelisted in security group of AWS RDS too but the app still timesout and fails with 502 error page. Please help.

Comment: Could you try to open RDS to everyone i.e. `0.0.0.0/0` just for debugging purposes and check if it works? If it does that means the IP address you have entered is incorrect. 
Also check if your RDS is publicly accessible, if not you would need to edit it and make it publicly accessible.

Comment: @Ryan Sure I just added 0.0.0.0/0 in Inbound Rule but still getting 502 error page

Comment: Can you connect to the database by running your app locally?

Comment: https://vercel.com/knowledge/how-to-allowlist-deployment-ip-address

Comment: Can you create your RDS into the public subnet and give it a try?

Comment: Also, you need to check the security group to allow all IP or your IP to pass-through

Comment: Thanks @Tim and everyone else but this way I can't push it to production with my db exposed to all IPs so I am dropping this use-case and converting my NextJS app to CRA based UI which will be deployed to S3 so that RDS and S3 can have common security protocol. I have tested the RDS with EC2 sharing common security group and they connect really well and works out of the box. Thank you everyone again.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone this has turned frustrating for me and this way I can't push it to production with my RDS db exposed to all IPs so I am dropping this use-case and converting my NextJS app to CRA based UI which will be deployed to S3 so that RDS and S3 can have common security protocol. I have tested the RDS with EC2 sharing common security group and they connect really well and works out of the box. Thank you everyone once again.